# Sharing Youtube video to Facebook using FBStreamDialog

Tags: facebook, video, sharing

I am developing an iPad application in which I need to share a Youtube video link to Facebook.
I am using FBStreamDialog for image sharing as follows:
But, I do not know how to share the video (I wanted to know about the parameters like media type, src, href etc)

```
FBStreamDialog* dialog = [[[FBStreamDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
dialog.delegate = self;
dialog.targetId = <facebookUserId?;
dialog.userMessagePrompt = @"What's in your mind?";
dialog.attachment = @"{\"name\":\"Sample Photo\","
                    "\"href\":\"http://abstract.desktopnexus.com/wallpaper/250923\","
                         "\"caption\":\"MyAppName\",\"description\":\"Testing share\","
                         "\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\","
                         "\"src\":\"http://static.desktopnexus.com/wallpapers/250923-bigthumbnail.jpg\","
                         "\"href\":\"http://abstract.desktopnexus.com/wallpaper/250923\"}],"
                        "\"properties\":{\"another link\":{\"text\":\"Facebook home page\",\"href\":\"http://www.facebook.com\"}}}"

[dialog show];
```

Could someone help me?
Thanks and Regards,
Deepa

Answer (score 1):

I have explained [here](http://startdevelopment.blogspot.com/2011/04/facebook-share-meta-tags.html?ref=sf) all the Facebook Meta tags which are used for sharing.
You can have a look at this post, it may be useful.